# Hazard rate discrete hazard model

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, survival, hazard

Once I have the estimates Beta (Coef) from a discrete hazard model (losgitic regression). How do I compute the hazard rate?

Example from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/alda/ch12.htm:

```
logitfit <- model$coef[i] + model$coef[2]*j + model$coef[3]*k + model$coef[4]*j*k    
survivor = 1    
hazard = 1/(1 + exp(-logitfit)) # Is not this the probability of an event occurring?    
survivor = (1-hazard)*survivor #Is not this the probability of an event not occurring?
```

How is then the "hazard rate" obtained?

Comment: As Singer and willet point on in their text, the interesting value is the hazard, which is interpreted as in the discrete time case as the probability of event, in the interval of time, given that it has not happened prior.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a logistic regression model to estimate the risk that someone dies within a specific time period. There are no implicit assumptions about the instantaneous risk of death within that time interval, so you cannot obtain the hazard rate. However, you can interpolate the hazard to be constant across the time frame, so by using the the fitted risk (as you've calculated) divided by the time denominator, you will have an estimate of the hazard function.

If you want an explicit estimate of the hazard function, you need to use the exact failure times and either a parametric survival model (possibly piecewise) or smoothed estimates of the baseline hazard from the Cox regression model.

Comment: Therefore, by using the fitted risk (as you've calculated) divided by the time denominator, you will have an estimate of the hazard function. How does it translate to code in r? hazard/t if t equals time?